# Mysql Long Process List and Auto Restart

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, server

I have an old website that uses big database and I do not want to upgrade it now. The issue is the mysql database has some queries takes very long time when high traffic about 4000 online users causes mysql to to reach 600%-800% and I have to manually restart the mysql server from WHM.

I want to use cron job simple shell script to read the mysql process list every 10 seconds and if any process time more than say 10 seconds it kill this process.

This is the query I found for doing such task:

```
mysql -e 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST where time>10 and command<>"Sleep"'
```

I think to get the process ID to kill I should use:

```
 mysql -e 'SELECT ID FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST where time>10 and command<>"Sleep"'
```

The output like that:

```
+------+
| ID   |
+------+
| 1095 |
| 1094 |
| 1081 |
| 1079 |
| 1078 |
| 1074 |
| 1040 |
| 1038 |
+------+
```

Now I have this output table, I just need to wrap this task in shell script to parse these process ID's and kill them.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the output in an array and use grep to filter only the digits.

```
mapfile -t array < <(mysql .... | grep -Ewo '[[:digit:]]+')
```

Another option is to use a `while read loop`

```
while read -r digits; do
  if [[ $digits =~ .*([[:digit:]]{4}).* ]]; then
    array+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
  fi
done < <(mysql ....)
```

Now `"${array[@]}"` has all that digits only value.

Kill it check if it is running, loop through it one by one and so on.

Comment: All good stuff, but I'm 99% certain there are `mysql` options that will skip formatting the output as a table with `+----+` etc. This will simplify the problem and make for cleaner code. Sorry, I don't had time to look up those options, but look for `--no-header` and similar. Good luck to all.

Comment: After long search, I think I came up with simple sh command but needs help confirming it is correct: `for i in $(mysql -Ne 'select id from information_schema.processlist where time>10 and command<>"Sleep";'); do
  mysql -e "kill ${i}"
done`

Comment: You need to loop through the elements of the array, `for in "${array[@]}"; do mysql -Ne 'select id from information_schema.processlist where time > 10 and command <>sleep; do mysql -e kill "$i"; done`

Comment: As far as i understand your question, you need to kill the pids right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with for specific databases user "db_user" to avoid system long process like backups etc:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(mysql -Ne 'select id from information_schema.processlist where USER="db_user" and time>20 and command<>"Sleep";'); do
  mysql -e "kill ${i}"
done
```

saved it as  mysql_kill_high_processes.sh and added it to the root user cron to run every minute.